# packaging jruby script into jar with all dependencies?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, packaging

is there any way to make my currently jruby script into a standalone single executable like jar or exe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rawr](http://Rawr.RubyForge.Org/) can do that, and also generate OSX `.app` packages.